Showing positive definiteness of joint process with cross-correlation
This paper claims that if $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are processes whose covariance matrices are
$$\mathsf{Cov}(Y_1)=L_1 L_1^\top$$
$$\mathsf{Cov}(Y_2)=L_2 L_2^\top,$$
where $L_1$ and $L_2$ are square root matrices and
$$\mathsf{Cov}(Y_1,Y_2)=\rho L_1 L_2^\top,$$
where $\rho$ measures the cross correlation between $Y_1$ and $Y_2$, then if both $L_1 L_1^\top$ and $L_2 L_2^\top$ are positive definite, then "clearly" so is
$$L L^\top=\begin{pmatrix}
L_1 L_1^\top & \rho L_1 L_2^\top\\
\rho L_2 L_1^\top & L_2 L_2^\top
\end{pmatrix}.$$
However, this is not clear to me. Is there a simple way to show that this is true? I tried generating data from this process and the resulting covariance matrix was not invertible. Either there was a bug in my code or the claim in the paper might be incorrect.
Since the paper is behind a paywall, I've attached screenshots of the relevant portion below.




Notice that $K^\intercal K$ is always positive semidefinite since $x^\intercal K^\intercal K x = \|Kx\|^2$ and this will be $>0$ provided $Kx \neq 0$ and therefore, this will be $>0$ for all $x \neq 0$ if $K$ is injective (note that this implies that the number of columns of $K$ is $\leq$ than the number of rows of $K$).
Then, $\rho \begin{bmatrix} L_1 \\ L_2 \end{bmatrix}  [L_1^\intercal, L_2^\intercal]  = \begin{bmatrix} \rho L_1L_1^\intercal &\rho L_1 L_2^\intercal \\ \rho L_2 L_1^\intercal &\rho L_2L_2^\intercal \end{bmatrix}$ will be positive definite if $[L_1^\intercal, L_2^\intercal]$ is injective and provided $\rho > 0$. Clearly $\begin{bmatrix} (1-\rho) L_1L_1^\intercal &0 \\0 &(1-\rho) L_2L_2^\intercal \end{bmatrix} > 0$ provided each $L_1$ and $L_2$ are injective and $\rho < 1.$ Therefore, $\begin{bmatrix} L_1L_1^\intercal &\rho L_1 L_2^\intercal \\ \rho L_2 L_1^\intercal &L_2L_2^\intercal \end{bmatrix}$ will be positive definite, being the sum of two such matrices, if all conditions are satistisfied, which reduce to $0 < \rho < 1$ and $L_1^\intercal, L_2^\intercal, [L_1^\intercal, L_2^\intercal]$ being injective.

I appreciate your correct use of positive semidefinite but this begs another issue -- isn't the "square root matrix" here not a square root at all?  Notationally it looks like Cholesky, though perhaps the authors don't require $L$ to be low triangular, though presumably it is square.  If $A$ is "square root" of matrix $M$ at a minimum satisfies the relation $A^2=M$.

I use positive definite below to mean non-negative eigenvalues, because that's how I think the OP uses it.
Your matrix is $\rho K^TK +(1-\rho) D$ with $K:=(L_1 \; L_2)$ and $D$ being block diagonal with diagonal blocks $L_iL_i^T$.
Since the sum of positive definite matrices is positive definite, and since Gramians (matrices of the form $K^TK$ for any $K$) are always positive definite, and since block diagonal matrices with positive definite blocks are positive definite, and since positive definite matrices scaled by non-negative scalars are positive definite, your matrix is positive for all $\rho\geq -1$.

Gramians are not always positive definite, they are always positive semidefinite, and they need to have full range to be positive definite, and even they they might not be positive definite (e.g., $K = [1,0]$ and $K^\intercal K$ is not positive definite, despite $K$ being of full range)..

@WilliamM. Many textbooks use positive definite to mean what you call positive semi-definite. Clearly that's the convention the article in the OP uses, given that covariance matrices are characterized by what you call positive semi-definiteness.

argh... statisticians.

Clarified this definition in my answer.

It’s a little presumptuous to write $LL^T$ for the matrix which we want to prove is PSD. Let’s just call the matrix $M$ and look at the product $\textbf{x}^T M \textbf{x}$. For ease of dealing with the blocks say that $\textbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}.$ Now let, $u=L_1^Tx$ and $v=L_2^Ty$. Then we have that
$$\textbf{x}^T M \textbf{x} = u^Tu + \rho( u^Tv + v^Tu) + v^Tv.$$
We can rewrite this as:
$$(1-\rho)(u^Tu + v^Tv)  + \rho(u+v)^T(u+v) \geq 0$$
